# iOS: change width for an UIImageView in mode view "left"

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uianimation, cgsize

I have an UIImageView, this:
[image]

I want do an animation that show slowly this imageview from left.
Then I crop in xib this imageview with mode "left" and I want to enlarge it with this code.
I crop width at 3 point and it start with size (3,28) and it should finish with size (620,28)

I use this code to do it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"moveprogress" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:7.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [progressBar setFrame:CGRectMake(progressBar.frame.origin.x, progressBar.frame.origin.y, 620, progressBar.frame.size.height)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

but the animation don't work and it show immediately the imageview in its full size. why?

Comment: work fine? sure? in "mode left"???

Comment: yes it starts from left and increases the width of that view,finally it reaches to end point

Comment: for me it doesn't work, it appear immediately in full size...

Comment: Can you try with `[UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval) animations:^(void)animations];` (but might have the same result)

Comment: the solution: progressBar.clipsToBounds = YES; it work now...

Answer (score 0):

```
//initial frame
CGRect initalImageFrame = [imageView frame];
initalImageFrame.size.width = 3.0f;
[imageView setFrame:initalImageFrame];


//animation

CGRect fullImageFrame = [imageView frame];
fullImageFrame.size.width = 640.0f;
[UIView animateWithDuration:7.0f animations:^{
    [imageView setFrame:fullImageFrame];
}];
```